# Why is this ground and resistor connected here after the switches?

Tags: resistors, ground

I had recently asked a quiestion here: [Will this circuit for quiz buzzers work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108987/41235) and I got [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108987/41235).

I am trying to understand the circuit and I have understood most of it but there is only one part that I am not able to understand.

[image]

I don't understand electronics in theory properly so can you explain in *simple english* why this ground and resistor have been connected?

Comment: I think that without that resistors, the tension of the base is not fixed and probably will float when the keys/buttons are open.

Comment: @Luis What is the meaning of 'tension of base'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, they aren't required, but those resistors help speed up the turn-off of the associated transistors, and also help with noise immunity by pulling the base connections all the way to ground when the switches are open.

Comment: The standard term for this configuration is "pull-down resistors".